# How can I launch command-line python 2.7 programs into full screen by default on Windows?

Tags: windows, python-2.7, powershell, command-line

I want to launch my python programs into full screen or whenever i run it from cmd or powershell i always want to get the output into full screen. How can I do that ?

Answer (score 0):

Create a shortcut for .cmd file and modify the Shortcut tab under Properties. Choose "Maximized" from Run: section.

[image]

Comment: That's fine for my computer but what about if I want to run it to someone else computer. Say I made one terminal based game and I want my friends to play it. So now I can't tell to each of my friends door to door to do this process. Instead isn't there any way to inject a code in python so that the terminal opens full screen immediately when the run command on it is initiated ?